# django.forms - Getting formset_factory to process initial data, untouched by a user, through POST

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using `formset_factory` to generate a bunch of forms, but I'd also like some HTML to be displayed with these forms, specific to the objects that they will eventually save. Say:

```
Name: Chris
Color: Blue
Shoesize: [user input]

Name: Bologna
Color: Pink
Shoesize: [user input]
```

Where `Name` and `Color` are presented in HTML and `Shoesize` is a field of some sort. I've tried adding hidden fields with an initial value (initialized when the `formset_factory` is being created, using the `initial` argument), but when one tries to POST these forms, if they don't pass validation, the initial values go away and the hidden fields are empty (some of which are required).

I could include more than just the formset in the dictionary sent to my template, but I don't have a way of associating information w/ each form in the formset (except through an attribute in the form itself, which doesn't get passed during POST). I've tried actual form fields with the "disabled" attribute, but that doesn't send through validation, either.

Can I override the `__init__` method to include some variables (but then how would you pass these through to the `formset_factory` call?)

Is there a way of doing this, or is it best to just not use `formset_factory` and instead construct my own dictionary of forms (I'd prefer not to mess w/ `prefix`; `formset_factory` does a really nice job with generating numbered IDs and things like this for each form field).

**Edit:** This isn't a model form. It's a regular form.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically set an initial value, set it to disabled and just display it's value.

```
class SizeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
    size = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        name_default = kwargs.pop('name_default', None)
        super(form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if name_default:
            self.fields['name'].initial = name_default

<form>
    Name: {{ form.name.value }}
    Size: {{ form.size }}
</form>
```

Then when you call the form in your view you would pass it a `name_default` keyword argument.

Comment: Hey. I've briefly editted my question—but I'm not using ModelForm. I'm using just a regular form (sorry, I should have been clearer). No objects are instantiated until after the form is validated

Comment: Ah, now keep in mind that I'm using `formset_factory`, which I don't think takes kindly to different initial arguments for its forms (sorry to hassle you, but I *did* mention this in my post!).